# No internet on Debian Testing after resuming from suspend/hibernate

Tags: debian, networkmanager, suspend, hibernate

I'm running Debian Testing with kernel 4.14 on a Dell Inspiron 5567 and Intel Wireless 3165 (driver iwlwifi).

I'm having a problem with Network Manager: after resuming from suspend/hibernate I can connect to a wireless network but there's no internet. I can connect via Bluetooth tethering (that's actually how I am connected now); upon restart everything works fine. Here's info on dmesg that might be relevant:

```
[  127.961205] PM: hibernation exit
[  128.093977] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[  128.093982] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[  128.236229] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[  128.412174] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[  128.421404] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[  128.421484] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[  128.422207] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[  128.541945] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[  128.616265] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[  132.319776] wlp1s0: authenticate with f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0
[  132.324793] wlp1s0: send auth to f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0 (try 1/3)
[  132.330364] wlp1s0: authenticated
[  132.332430] wlp1s0: associate with f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0 (try 1/3)
[  132.340239] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[  132.357641] wlp1s0: associated
[  132.357695] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[  158.140921] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  158.150788] wlp1s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
[  158.158151] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[  158.174255] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[  160.106531] wlp1s0: authenticate with f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0
[  160.114505] wlp1s0: send auth to f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0 (try 1/3)
[  160.118406] wlp1s0: authenticated
[  160.120421] wlp1s0: associate with f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0 (try 1/3)
[  160.128040] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from f4:c6:13:22:a8:e0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[  160.132544] wlp1s0: associated
[  160.132615] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
```

I can't help notice two lines:

```
[  128.421404] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
```

and

```
[  158.150788] wlp1s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
```

I googled both of them but nothing relevant to this came up (they are related, apparently, to frequent disconnections from wifi, which is not my case).

I tried the solutions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade) but none of them worked; to wit:

1. restarting network manager via systemctl.
2. Removing and loading iwlmvm, THEN restarting nm via systemctl.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot mentioning that I tried replacing nm with wicd but removed the latter because bluetooth was not functioning properly; however I purged nm at some point, so maybe a config file was lost.

Comment: There are some bugs with that particular wifi. I unfortunately have no solution to share for Linux because in my case I solved it switching for OpenBSD. OpenBSD 6.1 also used to have problems with this particular wifi losing connection once in a while however 6.2 seems to have solved it. At least I will leave here the contribute that wifi chipset can be problematic

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem her on Debian stable with kernel 4.16.0-2-amd64 and Realtek r8169

> r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down

You can try to remove and reload the kenel driver before and after suspend.
Create a file 
*/lib/systemd/system-sleep/reset-network*

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here, e.g.:
  rmmod r8169
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resume here, e.g.:
  modprobe r8169
fi
```

Don't forget to make it executable with 
**chmod 755 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/reset-network**

In some cases the path might be  /user/lib/systemd/system-sleep/

You can add other modules too!

Comment: Thanks! I don't exactly remember how I solved this; maybe I reinstalled. I don't have this issue anymore, it was probably sovled by a kernel upgrade. If anyone else finds your solution useful I'll mark it as the answer. Again, thank you!